# Separate chain Hashing for avoiding Hash collision

Tags: hash, chaining

My knowledge of hash tables is limited and I am currently learning it. I have a question on Hash collision resolution by open hashing or separate chain hashing.

I understand that the hash buckets in this case hold the pointer to the linked list where all the elements that map into the same key are linked. so the search complexity would be in the order of o(n) where n is the number of elements in the linked list. Is there a way to make this simpler ?

Also if there is a constraint on the size of the linked list, say it can hold only 5 elements max and if more than 5 elements hash into the same bucket, what would be the best way to handle this scenario ?

Any pointers for learning more on the above and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hash collisions shouldn't be too common, otherwise you're doing something wrong (e.g. a bad hash function or not a big enough hash table). So the number of elements in each linked-list should be minimal and the O(n) complexity shouldn't be too bad.

You could theoretically replace it with one of many other data structures. A binary search tree, for example, would get O(log n) search time (assuming the items are comparable), but then insert time will be up to O(log n) instead of O(1), and it would take more space.

There should be no maximum on the number of elements in a list. If there were, you could probably resort to probing (e.g. linear probing), but deletions could be a nightmare as you may need to move elements around quite a bit.